# AngularJs directive create fixed div on page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fixed

I'm currently developing a document tree in AngularJS using a directive. It is part of the pages as  component, and is placed relative any other component currently on the page.

As part of the document tree I have a version modal that is displayed when selecting a file, displaying its information and available versions of the file.

But this modal need to be fixed on the screen, so that the user does not need to scroll to the top to see it.

But as the modal is part of the document tree component, just setting it to fixed does not accomplish this. It just set it to fixed in relation to the directive.

```
// This does not work.
.version-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5vh;
  right: 2vw;
  bottom: 5vh;
  width: 480px;
}
```

How would one go about to set a fixed position on a div through a directive, that could be nested down several levels of dom objects with relative positions and sizes? It works if I through the browser tools move the modal div out as a child to < body/>, but doing so through code breaks the application.

```
let bodyDiv = document.getElementById('body-container');
let versionDiv = document.getElementById('version-modal');
bodyDiv.appendChild(versionDiv);
```

As far as I understand, doing this the div looses its connection to $scope, and all functions and members are lost.

Comment: Are you using any library for the modal, e.g. [UI-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal)?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://sysgears.com/articles/moving-a-page-element-without-affecting-its-scope-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed positioning *should* work regardless of where the element is in the DOM hierarchy. It would be useful to have a jsfiddle or similar to take a look at this issue. Alternatively, the HTML of the element would be useful.

Your CSS is referencing `.version-modal` as a class, but you're successfully referencing the modal using `document.getElementById('version-modal')`. Does your element have a `version-modal` class attribute as well as a `version-modal` id attribute?

You may just need to add `class="version-modal"` to your modal, or change your CSS rule to:

```
#version-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5vh;
  right: 2vw;
  bottom: 5vh;
  width: 480px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have both the ID and the class set to the same. This because it was a quick fix to try to move the div programmatic. Hopefully I would no need it.

Comment: I thought that would probably be the case, just wanted to check! I can't see why your code wouldn't work to be honest. If you can get a jsfiddle up that demonstrates the issue then I'll take a look. Another thing to check: inspect the element in the dev tools and make sure its position is actually `fixed`. If you're using other libraries, they may be overriding your CSS rule.